# Why is this youtube embed video "sticking" to the screen in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, youtube

In chrome, on a mac, take a look at this page- http://www.davepoyzer.com/  (specifically the video in the first blog post)

When scrolling down the video image gets "stuck" to the screen. Why? How do I fix this? Any thoughts or ideas? I'm totally stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens in Chrome under Windows as well.

I don't know how to confirm this, but I think you have come across a bug with Flash and/or Chrome.  What I think is happening is that Chrome tells the Flash plugin where to draw, and Flash draws there.  Chrome seems to only render and care about objects in its current view.  When you scroll up or down, the Flash object is no longer in that view, and thus not updated, causing it to stick wherever it was prior to being scrolled off the screen.

You can see this behavior by changing the speed at which you scroll, catching different parts of the YouTube player in view.

I see nothing about your iframe or embedding that would cause this.  It's pretty clean.

**EDIT:**  Looks like this has been identified as a bug for quite some time:  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=48e7681c989e639d&hl=en

Comment: Very informative! Thank you. Maybe I should just use Vimeo? Haha.

Comment: @Dave, it seems that anything Flash will give you the same problem.  This includes Vimeo.  I'm willing to bet this bug extends to other plugins as well.  Also, hello from the Quad Cities.